# Run method before tomcat session end

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, tomcat7

Can one run a method in java or javascript before the allocated tomcat session expires? For ex. User 1's sessions expires which will in turn 'trigger' a method to run before it expires? So my question is, is there any way to tell if the sessions expires (ex. session exception) which will then trigger a function to be run?

I would appreciate it if someone could help me out, thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do using `HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed()` method.

Create a class that implements `HttpSessionListener` interface, and add your code inside the method `sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent)`

See the links [Session Listener Example](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/ListenerSession.shtml) and [Session Listener Example 2](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/)

And nevertheless [Javadocs are always there](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)

From javadoc:

```
void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) 
   Receives notification that a session is about to be invalidated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html). You can implement this interface and configure it using web XML as explained [here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/).